# passing props to a static React Components

Tags: reactjs

I have created a static method in a react Class component
when I pass props it does not seem to me that they are passed,
however, the children prop for passed without any problem 
[component calling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z3tf.png)

This is the component and the given props
when consoling I receive undefined !!
[The Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PRSA.png)

```
class Tabel extends Component {
static Head = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <span className="table-head">
        {children}
    </span>
)

static Body = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <div className="tabel-body">{children}</div>
)

render = () => (
    <div className='tabel-container' >
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
)

}
```

I am passing props like this

```
<Tabel.Cell
  mainContent='$10 175.00'
  subContent={{ content: '12.4%', classes: 'stock-up' }}
/>
```

Comment: It's better to put some code here. Linking to screenshots is not a good idea.

Comment: You have declared them as component class level static methods but you are  calling those as components which isn’t correct. The static methods needs to be called like functions like Component.staticFunctionName() but <Component.staticFunctionName />

Comment: @Think-Twice it's working normally, but the problem is with the forwarding the props!

Answer (score 1):

May be try like this

```
static Head = props => (
    <span className="table-head">
        {props.children}
        {props.prop1Name}
        {props.prop2Name}
    </span>
)
```